# Facebook Graph API /me/accounts not working in code

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I am trying to update my page details from another sample site.
I implemented the same previously. 
I got the access token of the page from /me/accounts.

Now, the /me/accounts is returning an empty set in javascript code.
But I am getting the correct response in Graph API explorer.

PS: I am able to get the page details using the auth token. The only problem is that /me/accounts is returning an empty array.

Comment: And did you select your own app id in GAE …?

Comment: The APP and Page is created by someone else. I am using the APP ID of this APP in the javascript code. He have added me as the admin of the APP and Page too. Is there an option to select the APP ID in GAE?

Comment: Application dropdown in the top right corner ...

Comment: I switched to the new App in GAE and now it is also returning an empty set. But I have the admin privilege of the App. Is there any other setting I need to make to get it working?

Comment: Did you grant the necessary permission?

Comment: Im not sure.. since another person added me as the admin of the app..
Can you please tell me how to grant permissions for a specific user?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? If you want permissions from the user, you send them through the login flow and request them.  // Via the "get token" button in GAE you can check which permissions are already granted, or you make a request for `/me/permissions` using the access token.